# How can i create/build columns for richTextBox to act like in listView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I can use this example method to create cells and rows on richTextBox but that's not close to what I want.

I want to be able to add/assign text to a column row just like in listView and also to be able to click at the top on each column name.

```
private void SetTableToRichtextbox()
{
    //Since too much string appending go for string builder
    StringBuilder tableRtf = new StringBuilder();

    //beginning of rich text format,dont customize this begining line              
    tableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1 ");

    //create 5 rows with 3 cells each

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        tableRtf.Append(@"\trowd");

        //A cell with width 1000.
        tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx1000");

        //Another cell with width 2000.end point is 3000 (which is 1000+2000).
        tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx3000");

        //Another cell with width 1000.end point is 4000 (which is 3000+1000)
        tableRtf.Append(@"\cellx4000");

        tableRtf.Append(@"\intbl \cell \row"); //create row

    }

    tableRtf.Append(@"\pard");

    tableRtf.Append(@"}");

    this.richTextBox1.Rtf = tableRtf.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It is very hard to modify rtf after creating it. Instead you should build up the data structure spearately, maybe in a listview, and then transform it to rtf. Making it interactive is next to impossible and I don't see it anywhere in the [rtf specs](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading40) - Also note that the RTB control only can display a subset of the full rtf specs.

Comment: I tried to use listView control instead of the richTextBox but for some reason with the listView everything slow and the whole program stuck i can't click on other buttons controls while the backgroundworker is working. With the richTextBox it's all working smooth.

Comment: This sounds totally weird. You surly have made mistakes in implementing it. A richTextbox is basically a text editor, not an interactive grid layout. ListView should work smoothly; you may need to open another question describing the problems with your LV attempt. Don't forget to explain what and how much the backgroundworker does and how it interacts with the listview!